# Concatenate multiple rows to one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

I have the below data and I have to concatenate the long text column and make it as a single row. The challenge part is only one row has the notification number and other rows are null. You cannot group by the notification number.

[image]

I need the output as 2 rows

```
row number  Notification Number Plant   Creation Date   Language    Lineno  Tag Long Text
1           10014354914         A057    43466            EN            1     >X  aaabbbcccdddeeefffggghhhjjjkkklll
2           10014354915         A057    43466            EN            1     >X  aaabbbcccdddeeefffgggpppqqqrrrsss
```

I have used cursor for this. But it is taking much time.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: please show sum sample data and output that you want..?

Comment: Just click the link provided. You will see the data and I need the output as https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAMi5.png

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not links to images. Also take a look at [mcve].

Comment: try to understand how markdown works, for example [here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_basics.html). This language is used to write posts on stackoverflow.

Comment: Please read the first paragraph of the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: The images are loaded. Please check.

Comment: hi @Peak can you please tell me one thing your data sequence will be means first row is null then some value then row null then some value then row null

Comment: Hi @Qaiser, I need to delete all the rows that has null in all the columns. So I will neglect it.

Comment: Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.notificationnumber ASC) as [Row_Number], d.notificationnumber as NotificatonNumber , d.Plant , d.CreateDate ,  d.[Language] , d.[LineNo] , d.Tag ,
STUFF((
         SELECT longtext as [text()]
            FROM testtable
            Where [row_number] >= d.[row_number] and [row_number] < d.MaxVal
            FOR XML PATH('')
         ), 1, 1, '')
 from (
Select  a.* , (Select min(b.[row_number]) from testtable b where b.[lineno] is  null and b.[row_number] > a.[row_number]) as Maxval from  Testtable a where a.notificationnumber is not null ) d

Comment: Perfect!!!!!!!!! Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using oracle:

```
with data("row number", "Notification Number","Plant","Creation Date","Language","Lineno","Tag","Long Text") as (
select 1,10014354914,'A057',43466,'EN',1,'>X','aaabbbcccdddeeefffggghhhjjjkkklll' from dual
union all
select 2,10014354915,'A057',43466,'EN',1,'>X','aaabbbcccdddeeefffgggpppqqqrrrsss' from dual)
select LISTAGG("Long Text",'') within group (order by "row number") from data;
```

if you are using ms-sql maybe try this:

```
SELECT u.[Long Text]  AS [text()]
            FROM yourtable u
            ORDER BY u.[row number]
            FOR XML PATH ('')
```

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts. I am using Microsoft SQL.